# Java - how to auto set width for img.getScaledInstance( );?

Tags: java, resize, height

I wanted to resize a image if it is too large, but i want it to keep it's aspect ratio, how can i just define it's height and let it automatically get it's width?

```
ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(image);

//Check if image size is more than 200

if(!checking){
    Image img = image2.getImage() ;  
    Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( "What to put here?", 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;  
    image2 = new ImageIcon( newimg );
}   

JButton newimage = new JButton(image2);
```

Comment: You can always get the ratio by dividing old height by new height (or width).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)),

> **If either width or height is a negative number then a value is substituted to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image dimensions**. If both width and height are negative, then the original image dimensions are used.

So you could just do,

```
img.getScaledInstance(-1, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
```

Comment: never knew that .that's the best way

Answer (score 3):

you should do some maths.find the ratio of height and old height then find new width

```
double Width=(200/(double)image2.getIconHeight())*image2.getIconWidth();
```

then you can set width

```
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( Width, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
```

Comment: WOW THX! still need to parse Width to int and that's it!